# How can I run a Python script as a Windows service using C# platform?

Tags: python, c#

I want to run python script on windows service C# platform.
I have a log file that the WritetoFile class logs. I have no problem saving data to file. I want to run python script every day at 6:00 am. I'm using the timer method, when the timer is enabled, I can run the class I specified. I don't have any problems with it either. When running the python script on the windows service platform, as you can see in the code below, only "python is started" is recorded in the log file. When I run the same code in console, python works. There is no problem with python script. The content of the python script doesn't matter, I couldn't even print the hello word text. According to my research, I can run a python script in windows service. Do I need to make a different setting on the windows service platform? Could you please help me?
The code is in below.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
string pythonScriptPath = "D:\\..\\report.py";
            string pythonInterpreter= "C:\\Users\\pam01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe";
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.FileName = pythonInterpreter;
            startInfo.Arguments = pythonScriptPath;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            WriteToFile(startInfo.ToString());
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.Start();
            //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            WriteToFile("python is started");
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            WriteToFile(output);
        }

        protected override void OnStop(
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
            if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
            {
                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.CloseMainWindow();
                process.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: _" I want to run python script every day at 6:00 am"_ - ditch the c# service and use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

Comment: There is no spoon - and no code either... Did you forget to add it?

Comment: ^^ To elaborate why I advertise for the WTS: a) It's the correct tool for the task. b) It gives you some capabilities for free, you would need to code explicitly with a custom built C# Service, including but not restricted to: error handling, handling missed calls, error notification (e.g. via email), etc.

Comment: Use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) and follow the [steps](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7325/how-to-run-a-python-script-windows-service-nssm/).